# C# XNA if-else and defaulting to first value

Tags: c#, if-statement, xna

So I am developing a custom `ButtonGUI` class for my game. Here's the initialization of the button object:

```
// Button code:
ButtonGUI btn1 = new ButtonGUI("Button 1", new Rectangle(150, 300, (int)myFont.MeasureString(menuButtons[0]).X, (int)myFont.MeasureString(menuButtons[0]).Y), myFont, Color.CornflowerBlue);
```

Now consider this code:

```
// Draw() method:
btn1.Draw(spriteBatch);

if (btnHover)
{
    btn1.btnRect = new Rectangle(140, 300, (int)hoverFont.MeasureString(menuButtons[0]).X, (int)hoverFont.MeasureString(menuButtons[0]).Y);
    btn1.btnFont = hoverFont;
    btn1.btnColour = Color.Red;
}
else
{
    btn1.btnRect = new Rectangle(150, 300, (int)myFont.MeasureString(menuButtons[0]).X, (int)myFont.MeasureString(menuButtons[0]).Y);
    btn1.btnFont = myFont;
    btn1.btnColour = Color.CornflowerBlue;
}
```

This would be OK if I had only 1 button... But if I have like 10 buttons or more? This really isn't what `DRY` suggests. I feel like I'm missing something, there must be a way to return button properties to their default values once the condition is no longer met without doing the whole thing manually, or is there? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why isn't the hover/not-hover code inside the `ButtonGUI` class? Also, I'm not sure why you prefix your properties with `btn`, it should be apparent that its part of the button...

Comment: Have you encountered the concept of Game Components yet? This is an easy way to get UI functionality in a small game project and is how I ended up implementing UI controls in my own project. Take a look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.drawablegamecomponent.aspx. This way you can keep all the button logic in the button class.

Comment: @E.Moffat Well, I was expecting to get a more generic C# type of suggestion (some kind of reserved special word or anything), without the need of modifying my entire XNA code... Yes, I've read about `DrawableGameComponent`s but many people don't favor them. I wanted to work with normal classes.

Comment: @RonBeyer Well since each button is an individual object how am I expected to change its properties in the class? Maybe use `array`s and `foreach` loops?

Comment: Yes, you add the buttons to an array when you create them, and then loop over them, but if you had the logic for hover/not hover inside the button, you could do something like (assuming `btnList` is a `List<ButtonGUI>`: `btnList.ForEach(b => b.IsHovered = true);` then let the `IsHovered` property set the other ones to the appropriate values, keeping code in one place.

Comment: Yes, I will give that concept a try too...

Comment: @JohnyP. Ron's suggestion is similar to what game components do - only the logic for the 'Hovered' property would be entirely contained within the button and modified in the button's `Update` method (checking MouseState), which is called by the framework each frame. I'll admit that game components don't make much sense for large projects but when I was starting out with my UI library, it made it *much* easier to segment my code into more cohesive units.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may make sense to create a structure to hold all of the values that may change.

```
class ButtonData
{
    // put members corresponding to each member of ButtonGUI you wish 
    //     to change
}

class ButtonSwapper
{
     ButtonGUI myButton;
     ButtonData hoverData;
     ButtonData notHoverData;

     void change(bool hover)
     {
          ButtonData dataToUse = hover ? hoverData : notHoverData;

          // set each relevant member of myButton to its pair in
          //    dataToUse
     }
}
```

then call `change` as necessary.

Comment: Hmmm, easy, quick, efficient, readable. I will give it a try, thanks!